# Does Keras preprocessing layers apply to the validation set?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I was reading the [data augmentation article on Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation) and they allow one to make preprocessing layer a part of the model:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    data_augmentation,
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    # Rest of your model
])
```

I'm wondering whether one or both of the resize_and_rescale and data_augmentation layers are also applied to the validation set during training?

Comment: You don't need to wonder. Write a program to test your hypothesis and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which type of augmentation you are using. For example if you use resizing layer or a rescale layer they are applied even during inference mode, that is they would be applied to the valiation data in model.fit. For other augmentation layers like RandomFlip layer the documentation states:

```
During inference time, the output will be identical to input.
```

So you have to look up the information on the type of layer you are using. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_preprocessing/) From what I could gather I think only the resizing and rescaling layers remain active during inference mode.